# Categorize the highest value output among different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe I want to choose the highest value among columns A,B,C. Then I will let to categorize the highest value in my output dataframe. I would also like to include a special condition, where if all the values are negative, then the output will return as N.A.

input df:

```
            A         B         C
Date            
2020-01-05  3.57      5.29      6.23
2020-01-04  4.98      9.64      7.58
2020-01-03  3.79      5.25      6.26
2020-01-02  3.95      5.65      6.61
2020-01-01  -3.10     -7.20     -8.16
```

output df:

```
            A         B         C       HIGHEST_CAT
Date            
2020-01-05  3.57      5.29      6.23    C
2020-01-04  4.98      9.64      7.58    B   
2020-01-03  3.79      5.25      6.26    C
2020-01-02  3.95      5.65      6.61    C
2020-01-01  -3.10     -7.20     -8.16   N.A.
```

How could I achieve this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) with condition for test all values bellow `0` by [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['HIGHEST_CAT'] = np.where(df.lt(0).all(axis=1), np.nan, df.idxmax(axis=1))
```

Or in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with default `np.nan`, so not necessary specify:

```
df['HIGHEST_CAT'] = df.idxmax(axis=1).mask(df.lt(0).all(axis=1))
```

Or:

```
df.loc[df.gt(0).all(axis=1), 'HIGHEST_CAT'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
               A     B     C HIGHEST_CAT
Date                                    
2020-01-05  3.57  5.29  6.23           C
2020-01-04  4.98  9.64  7.58           B
2020-01-03  3.79  5.25  6.26           C
2020-01-02  3.95  5.65  6.61           C
2020-01-01 -3.10 -7.20 -8.16         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
In [375]: df['HIGHEST_CAT'] = df.idxmax(axis=1).where(df.gt(0).all(axis=1))

In [376]: df
Out[376]: 
               A     B     C HIGHEST_CAT
Date                                    
2020-01-05  3.57  5.29  6.23           C
2020-01-04  4.98  9.64  7.58           B
2020-01-03  3.79  5.25  6.26           C
2020-01-02  3.95  5.65  6.61           C
2020-01-01 -3.10 -7.20 -8.16         NaN
```